# Python 3, Connect 4, noob Debugging issue with " 'int' object is not subscriptable "

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been reading through the other posts/questions about '**int**' object is not subscript-able and I do not see this question answered or I don't realize it is similar and has been.

As the subject says, I am trying to write a Connect 4 game. I have finished with the manual 2 player and am now working on a sort of very basic AI. I'm trying to work through all the bugs in this code before I move on.
 The problem is where I am trying to give a value to moves the AI could possibly make. If the move is a good one, I want to make that move or I want it to remember the column for that move if it is a future move. It should be able to look ahead 3 moves or more even.
I apologize for formatting and if my question isn't explained well enough. SO is very new to me.

The error I get in wing 101 is:

> File "C:\Users\Dad\Desktop\Wing IDE 101 5.0.9\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 229, in 
>     File "C:\Users\Dad\Desktop\Wing IDE 101 5.0.9\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 216, in playGameWith
>     File "C:\Users\Dad\Desktop\Wing IDE 101 5.0.9\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 63, in nextMove
>   builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Is there anyone with knowledge of this issue and willing to give some pointers? My class has not been shown how to use the wing debugger yet.

Thank you!

```
import random       # needed later when I figure out how to do better AI
import time         # in case i want to slow it down for debug

class Player:
''' generates moves given a board
'''

def __init__(self,ox,ply):
    self.ply = ply
    #self.tbt = tbt
    self.ox = ox

def oppCh(self):                    # opposing checker
    if oMove == 'o':
        return 'o'
    return 'x'

def scoresFor ( self , b , ox , ply ):
    scores = []
    for col in range (b.width):
        if b.allowsMove(col):
            b.addMove (col,ox)                # make move
            if b.winsFor(ox) == True:     # check did I win
                scores += [100,col]
            elif ply == 1 :                     # if ply = 1
                scores += [50,col]
            else:                               # op = opposite player
                if ox == 'x':
                    op = 'o'
                else:
                    op = 'x'
                oplist = []
                oplist = self.scoresFor(b,op,ply-1)
                scores += [100 - max(oplist),col]
            b.delMove(col)       #remove move
        else:
            scores += [-1]
            ply = ply - 1
    return scores # a list of 2 number lists ie... (50,2)  (50,3) etc

def tieBreakMove(self,scores):      # tbt Tie Break Type - not implemented yet
    if self.tbt == 'LEFT':
        return
    if self.tbt == 'RIGHT':
        return
    if self.tbt == 'RANDOM':
        return

def nextMove (self,b):
    scores = self.scoresFor(b,self.ox,self.ply)
    print (scores)          # for debugging, will delete after
    col = max(scores)[1]     # I want the column for the max value
    return col
```

---

```
class Board:
''' a datatype representing a c4 board with rows and columns
'''
def __init__ ( self,width,height ):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.data = []                  #  this will be the board

    for row in range (self.height):
        boardRow = []
        for col in range (self.width):
            boardRow += [' ']       #  add a space to row
        self.data += [ boardRow ]

def __repr__ (self):
    ''' returns a str representation for an object of type Board
    '''
    s = ''
    for row in range ( self.height ):
        s += '|'
        for col in range ( self.width ):
            s += self.data [row][col] + '|'
        s += '\n'
    s += '--' * self.width + '-\n'
    for col in range ( self.width ):
        s+= ' ' + str(col % 10)
    s += '\n'
    return s

def allowsMove (self,col):
    if 0 <= col < self.width:
        if self.data [0][col] == ' ':
            return True
    return False

def isFull (self):
    for col in range(self.width):
        if self.data[0][col] == ' ':
            return False
    return True

def addMove (self,col,ox):
    if self.allowsMove(col):
        for row in range (self.height):
            if self.data [row][col] != ' ':
                self.data [row-1][col] = ox
                return
        self.data [self.height-1][col] = ox

def clearBoard (self):
    for row in range (self.height):
        for col in range (self.width):
            self.data[row][col] = ' '
    return

def delMove ( self , col ):
    for row in range (self.height):
        if self.data[row][col] != ' ':
            self.data[row][col] = ' '
            return

def winsFor (self,ox):
    # check for horizontal wins
    for row in range (0,self.height):
        for col in range (0,self.width-3):
            if self.data [row][col] == ox and \
                self.data [ row ][ col + 1 ] == ox and \
                self.data [ row ][ col + 2 ] == ox and \
                self.data [ row ][ col + 3 ] == ox:
                return True
    # check for vertical wins
    for row in range (0,self.height -3):
        for col in range (0,self.width):
            if self.data [row][col] == ox and \
                self.data [ row + 1 ][ col ] == ox and \
                self.data [ row + 2 ][ col ] == ox and \
                self.data [ row + 3 ][ col ] == ox:
                return True
    # check for diagonal wins NW to SE  \  
    for row in range (0,self.height-3):
        for col in range (0,self.width-3):
            if self.data [row][col] == ox and \
                self.data [ row + 1 ][ col + 1 ] == ox and \
                self.data [ row + 2 ][ col + 2 ] == ox and \
                self.data [ row + 3 ][ col + 3 ] == ox:
                return True
    # check for diagonal wins NE to SW  /  
    for row in range (0,self.height-3):
        for col in range (3,self.width):
            if self.data [row][col] == ox and \
                self.data [ row + 1 ][ col - 1 ] == ox and \
                self.data [ row + 2 ][ col - 2 ] == ox and \
                self.data [ row + 3 ][ col - 3 ] == ox:
                return True
    return False

def hostGame ( self ):
    while True:
        print(self)
        while True:                     # while loop X
            m = int(input ('For player X, enter move.'))
            if self.allowsMove(m):
                break
            else:
                print("bad move")       # end while loop X
        self.addMove (m,'x')
        if self.winsFor('x') == True:
            print ('Player X has won.')
            print (self)
            return
        elif self.isFull() == True:
            print ('The game is a tie, the board is full.')
            print (self)
            return
        print(self)
        while True:                     # While loop O
            m = int(input ('For player O, enter move.'))
            if self.allowsMove(m):
                break
            else:
                print ("bad move")      # End while loop O
        self.addMove (m,'o')
        if self.winsFor('o') == True:
            print ('Player O has won.')
            print (self)
            return
        elif self.isFull() == True:
            print ('The game is a tie, the board is full.')
            print (self)
            return
def playGameWith (self,aiPlayer): # X = player, O = aiPlayer
    while True:
        print(self)
        while True:                     # while loop X
            xMove = int(input ('For player X, enter move.'))
            if self.allowsMove(xMove):
                break
            else:
                print("bad move, human")       # end while loop X
        self.addMove (xMove,'x')
        if self.winsFor('x') == True:
            print ('Player X has won.')
            print (self)
            return
        elif self.isFull() == True:
            print ('The game is a tie, the board is full.')
            print (self)
            return
        print(self)
        oMove = aiPlayer.nextMove(b)            # ai move get
        self.addMove (oMove,'o')                # add ai move
        if self.winsFor('o') == True:
            print ('The Computer O has won. Bad luck human.')
            print (self)
            return
        elif self.isFull() == True:
            print ('The game is a tie, the board is full.')
            print (self)
            return
```

---

```
# for testing
b =Board (7,6)              # create Board
aiPlayer = Player('o',3)    # player, ply 0 < ply < 4
b.playGameWith(aiPlayer)    # game plays w/ aiplayer
```

Comment: Just to clarify, spelling does not count when the item in question is a quote. "int object is not subscript-able" is not the error, the error was "'int' object is not subscriptable ”. Correcting may make it pretty for humans, but could also lead to misinterpreting the question or facts.

Answer (score 0):

`col = max(scores)[1]` is the problem max returns an `int` like `47` so you are saying `col = 74[1]`

I suspect you actually need:

```
col = max([x[1] for x in scores])
```

Comment: This answer isn't working. Same error :/  Since scores is a list of pairs, why doesn't max(scores) return a pair (with 0 and 1 elements)?

Comment: Since you are adding lists rather than tupples, (wrong brackets [] + [50, 3] + [50, 4] = [50, 3, 50, 4] so max = 50... scores.append((50, 3)) will do what you wish - also in at least one place you are adding a singleton.